# Firebase messaging missing Authentication key in MongoDB trigger functions:

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Please I need help. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am trying to send push notification from http request but I keep getting this error:

> The request was missing an Authentication Key. Please, refer to section "Authentication" of the FCM documentation, at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.

I am currently doing this:

```js
 const response =  await context.http.post({
    url:"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
    header:{"Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization":"key= Web Server Key"},
    body:{
    "to": usersPushToken, // From FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    "notification": {
      "title": "Title", 
      "body": "body",
      "clickAction": 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
      "sound": 'default',
      },
    }
    },
  encodeBodyAsJSON: true,
  });
```

My web server key **(Cloud Messaging API (Legacy))** I also tried API key:
[image: Cloud Messaging API (Legacy)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This was my fault** `(headers not header)`. But I will leave this answer for anyone using **Flutter**, **MongoDB**, and **Firebase Messaging**.

```js
const response =  await context.http.post({
    url:"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
    "headers":{"Content-Type": ["application/json"],  //Must be in array
            "Authorization":["key= Web Server Key"]}, //Must be in array
    "body":{
    "to": usersPushToken, // From FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    "notification": {
      "title": "Title", 
      "body": "body",
      "clickAction": 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
      "sound": 'default',
      },
     }
    },
  encodeBodyAsJSON: true,
  });
```